# how to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

im working on a node passport login authentication but im stack on this error which makes it hard for me to run my node server

/home/emil/Documents/myapp/app/routes.js:14
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined

how can i fix it?

my code:
server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: false
}));
app.use(session({
secret: 'anystringoftext',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true
}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.use('/', function(req, res){
//  res.send('Our First Express program!');
//  console.log(req.cookies);
//  console.log('===============');
//  console.log(req.session);
//});

require('./app/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
```

routes.js:

```
var User = require('./models/user');

module.exports = function (app, passport) {
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

 app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login.ejs', {
        message: req.flash('loginMessage')
    });
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}));

app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup.ejs', {
        message: req.flash('signupMessage')
    });
});

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));

app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
   res.render('profile.ejs', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/:username/:password', function (req, res) {
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.local.username = req.params.username;
    newUser.local.password = req.params.password;
    console.log(newUser.local.username + " " + newUser.local.password);
    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });
    res.send("Success!");
})
};

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
}
res.redirect('/login');
}
```

passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../app/models/user');

module.exports - function(passport) {

passport.serializeUser(function(usser, done){
   done(null, user.id); 
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
   User.findById(id, function(err, user){
       done(err, user);
   });
});

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, email, password, done){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        User.findOne({'local.username': email}, function(err, user){
            if(err)
                return done(err);
            if(user){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That account exists'));
            } else {
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.local.username = email;
                newUser.local.password = password;

                newUser.save(function(err){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                })
            }
        })

    });
}));

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, email, password, done){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        User.findOne({ 'local.username': email}, function(err, user){
           if(err)
               return done(err);
            if(!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found'));
            if(user.local.password != password)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'invalid password'));
        }
           return done(null, user);  
    })
    })
}
))
```

Comment: At least one bug immediately found: `module.exports - function(passport) {`... should be `=` not `-`. Anyway, you shouldn't expect people to debug all your code. Post the minimum code you are having problems with, no one wants to read all that code unless they're working on it.

Comment: ok thanks. will do that next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not passed `passport` to the routes. `require('./app/routes.js')(app);` should be `require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport)` in server.js;

Comment: now im getting an error on this line of code. is there anything to change?    ' app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
        res.render('login.ejs', {
            message: req.flash('loginMessage')
        });
    });'

Comment: man I did exactly what you typed but the result is still the same https://pastebin.com/y1Pw35Bt

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same error after many trials AND i found this basic error. Related to module.exports that it export a object everytime.

while i was writting this and getting error:
***module.exports = User;***

But This solved my error, ***module.exports = {User};***

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:{
       type: String,
   },
   email:{
       type: String,
   },
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const User = new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);



module.exports = {User};
```

and i was requiring it, in this way:
***const {User} = require("./models/User");***